# Gtk TextView - how to change width of cursor?

Tags: ruby, gtk

I'm using a Gtk TextView in a small Ruby program. The text cursor is a vertical bar, only 1 pixel wide. I have changed its colour to red but it is still barely visible. Can it be made wider?

---

```
require "gtk2"
tl = Gtk::Window.new
vb = Gtk::VBox.new false, 0
tl.add vb
sw = Gtk::ScrolledWindow.new
tview = Gtk::TextView.new
tbuf = Gtk::TextBuffer.new
tview.set_buffer tbuf
tview.set_wrap_mode Gtk::TextTag::WRAP_WORD
tview.set_justification Gtk::JUSTIFY_FILL
font = Pango::FontDescription.new "Serif, 11"
tview.modify_font font
red = Gdk::Color.new 65535, 20000, 20000
tview.modify_cursor red, red
sw.add tview
vb.pack_start sw, true, true, 0
tl.show_all
tbuf.set_text %(I'm using a Gtk TextView in a small Ruby program. The text cursor is a vertical bar, only 1 pixel wide. I have changed its colour to red but it is still barely visible. Can it be made wider?)
Gtk.main
```

Comment: can you post the code you have so far?

Comment: Apologies for the (lack of) formatting: the semicolons show where the lines ended.

Comment: don't post code in comments but rather edit your question to include the code so it can be formatted and readable.

Comment: Ok, done ... should be clearer.